# Not getting BarChart in Winform Application

Tags: c#, winforms, bar-chart

I am trying to show a dynamic barchart from database in winform application but it is not coming and giving me `Argument out of Exception` error at `var p2 = series.Points[arrlocationSTD];` when `arrlocationSTD=1`. Here is my code in c#..

```
    void LoadBarChart(string qurystring)
    {


            if (calltype.Equals("TRANSFERED"))
            {

                totalTransfered = dr["SummaryOfCalls"].ToString();
                intTRANSFERED = int.Parse(totalTransfered, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

               if (i == 0)
                {
                arrlocationTransferred = i;

                series.Points.Add(intTRANSFERED);
                var p7 = series.Points[arrlocationTransferred];
                p7.Color = Color.Yellow;
                p7.AxisLabel = "TRANSFERED";
                p7.LegendText = "TRANSFERED";
                p7.Label = totalTransfered;

                i++;
                }
                else
                {
                arrlocationTransferred = i;

                series.Points.Add(intTRANSFERED);
                var p7 = series.Points[arrlocationTransferred];
                p7.Color = Color.Yellow;
                p7.AxisLabel = "TRANSFERED";
                p7.LegendText = "TRANSFERED";
                p7.Label = totalTransfered;

                }

            }

        }

        barChart.Invalidate();

        pnlBar.Controls.Add(barChart);
    }
```

Please help me to resolve this.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Sounds like the `series.Points` collection contains one or zero elements.  Put a breakpoint on that line and use a watch to see the content of that collection.

Comment: You added only a single point to the series.  It index is 0, not 1.

Comment: @HansPassant If i have multiple points Do i always need to add in series in 0,1,2 etc or randomly will also work.

Comment: If Points is a List or Array, it will be ordered using zero-based indexing.  You could change it to a Dictionary collection then it will use the 'index' you provide as the Key.  E.g. `private Dictionary<int,int> Points;` then `series.Points.Add(arrlocationsSTD,intSTD);`

Comment: @MikeofSST I have updated my post with my full code for Barchart .Please have a look as i am totally not getting the way to resolve this..

Comment: @MikeofSST Please help me implementing this `Dictionary` in my case..Thanks

Comment: @MikeofSST R u helping me Sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add your additional processing, but the following might help.

I'd strongly recommend that you get the chart showing your data correctly before you start changing colour properties and such.

```
void LoadBarChart(string qurystring)
{
    String conn = Strings.ConnectionString; // You fill this in.

    Dictionary<String,int> callSummariesByTypeOfCall =
        new Dictionary<String,int>();

    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conn);
    MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(qurystring, con);
    con.Open();
    MySqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();

    // Get the data into a dictionary
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        String calltype = dr["TypeOfCall"].ToString();
        int summary = int.Parse(dr["Calls"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        callSummariesByTypeOfCall[calltype] = summary;
    }

    // Do any other processing you need here

    // Bind the data onto the Series
    Series series = new Series
    {
        Name = "series2",
        IsVisibleInLegend = false,
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column
    };
    series.Points.DataBindXY(
        callSummariesByTypeOfCall.Keys,
        callSummariesByTypeOfCall.Values);
    barChart.Series.Add(series);
    barChart.Invalidate();

    pnlBar.Controls.Add(barChart);
}
```

Comment: `barChart.Series.DataBindXY` error on this `DataBindXY` does not exists

Comment: Sorry.  Missed the `.Points`.  Updated the answer.

Comment: R u helping me in this ?